Where to Ask Blender and Python-Related Questions?
Which site should I use if I want to ask questions related to Blender or Python in Blender? Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow?

The accepted rules state that if it is a general Python programming question it should go on Stack overflow, if it has something specific to Blender, uses specific BPI operators or the Blender Python API, then it can be posted here
